# Как выполнить программу, имея файл с исходным кодом

Tags: java

Написал простую Hello World программу в блокноте и сохранил, как надо.

Что делать дальше, чтобы из этого получилась программа?

Comment: Э-м-м... Нажать кнопку для компиляции в IDE?.. Суть ваших затруднений не ясна, попробуйте более подробно описать вашу проблему

Comment: Ну если в блокноте то тогда лучше через командную строку запустить . Но лучше почитайте Шилда Java 8  там расписаны первые шаг

Comment: Я пытался через командную строку но вообще без результата

Comment: Предлагаю ответить, как компилировать и запускать код из командной строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, проголосовал за переоткрытие. если откроют, готов написать нужные команды для *gnu/linux*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin даю добро :)

Comment: @alexolut, добро взял.

Answer (score 7):

в операционной системе *gnu/linux*, при наличии установленных программ `javac` и `java`, вот такой файл:

```
class helloworld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world!");
    }
}
```

сохранённый в текущем каталоге под именем `helloworld.java`, можно скомпилировать командой:

```
$ javac helloworld.java
```

и запустить полученный файла `helloworld.class` командой:

```
$ java helloworld
```

вывод:

```
hello world!
```

---

установить программы `javac` и `java` можно разными способами, наиболее простой и логичный — из репозитория вашего дистрибутива. например, в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах это можно сделать командой:

```
$ sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Comment: команды: `javac helloworld.java` и `java helloworld` принципиально отличаются на windows и linux?:)

Comment: @Grundy, у меня есть лишь подозрение о том, что в *ms/windows* действия, возможно, примерно аналогичны. проверить это подозрение мне негде, потому в ответе про него не упоминал.